# Concatenating Dataframes and if there is an 'in place' TfidfVectorizer

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, tfidfvectorizer

I have been given the task of making a sentiment prediction model based on movie reviews. The `train` dataset along with the feature `movie_review` contains other features such as `movie_name`, `release_date` etc. and the `sentiment` (positive or negative).

I have vectorized the the feature `movie_review` using the `TfidfVectorizer()` function of sklearn. Now I am trying to concatenate two dataframes :-

1. The `train` dataset which is of shape (156311, 5)
2. The dataframe which I got as the output of `TfidfVectorizer()` after vectorizing the `movie_review` feature column of the `train` dataset. Shape of this dataframe is  (156311 × 65220)

In order to concatenate the two dataframes, I use the following function,

`pd.concat([train, review_vectorized], axis=1)`

The problem is that every time I try to run time the function, the RAM memory runs out and the google collab crashes.

Is there a more efficient way of concatenating dataframes?
Or even better, is there a way to vectorize the textual column 'in-place'?  So as we wouldn't need to create a separate dataframe with the vectorized text and the concatenate with the original dataframe?